# Error debugging this restsql code?

Tags: mysql, rest

I'm trying to test the module with a sample web service from http://www.espressologic.com/developer-restful-services-for-sql-data/

But getting problem with these two logics, can anyone suggest what I am missing

•   **Validation Validation balance <= credit_limit**

```
return row.balance <= row.credit_limit;
```

**• Validation Javascript validation credit_limit != maxLimit**

```
var maxLimit = 999;   
if (row.credit_limit == maxLimit)   
    return false;   
else   
    return true;
```